# Writing in Arabic appears inverted in the terminal when writing using Python in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, terminal, arabic

When I type in Arabic in the print commands, for example, or any other commands in Visual Studio Code, the result appears in the terminal in reversed Arabic .[for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMJXu.png)

```
print ("السلام عليكم")
```

it's appeared in terminal like:

```
م ك ي ل ع م ا ل س ل ا
```

Comment: look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/63846811/9182171

Comment: The terminal also needs to support the transitions between left-to-right and right-to-left for this to work correctly. If you `cat yourcode.py` and both the Latin and Arabic parts are displayed correctly, the terminal works. I'd expect the one built into VS Code to work though.

Comment: Most console/terminal applications have no or poor bidi support. The usual hack to to mangle the text using python-bidi and arabic-reshaper packages. But this will only work for Arabic and Persian/Farsi. It isn't a general solution.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few possible approaches:

1. Do not use the vscode terminal, choose an alternative terminal/console with better bidi support. Although most terminals/consoles have poor bidi support
2. Convert Unicode Arabic text from logical to visual ordering using the `python-bidi` and `arabic-reshaper` packages.
3. Convert Unicode Arabic text from logical to visual ordering using the `pyfribidi` package.

As indicated in the OP, the vscode terminal has serious bidirectional text rendering issues, so the simple code will not work:

```py
text = "السلام عليكم"
print(text)
```

So instead, using `python-bidi` and `arabic-reshaper`:

```py
import arabic_reshaper
from bidi.algorithm import get_display
print(get_display(arabic_reshaper.reshape(text)))
```

`python-bidi` is responsible in convert from logical to visual reordering, and `arabic-reshaper` converts Arabic characters to appropriate presentational forms.

Using `pyfribidi`:

```py
from pyfribidi import log2vis, RTL
print(log2vis(text, RTL))
```

`pyfribidi` is a wrapper around the **fribidi** library. If you have **libraqm** support enabled for bidi support in **Pillow** or in the **mplcairo** backend for **matplotlib** you probably already have **fribidi** available.

Personally I prefer option 1. Options 2 and 3 are ugly hacks, but sometimes necessary.

[image]

As an example of what option 1, may look like, using the Terminal app on macOS:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The terminal in Visual Studio Code (and many other code editors) doesn't fully support right-to-left text rendering.

You can try to use the following codes to make it work:

```
def print_arabic(text):
    print(text[::-1])

print_arabic("السلام عليكم")
```

Comment: it is insufficient in many cases to simply reverse the string. It is necessary to use or implement a tool that will convert unicode output from logically ordered text, to visually ordered text.